# Concurrency and kafka

Tags: spring-kafka

I have topic with 2 partitions, in my spring boot application I configure kafka with ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainer and setConcurrency(3).

Configuration:

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MyMessage> configureKafka(
ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MyMessage> factory,
KafkaContainerErrorHandler containerErrorHandler,
DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor<String, MyMessage> rollbackErrorHandler) {
   factory.setErrorHandler(containerErrorHandler);
   factory.setAfterRollbackProcessor(rollbackErrorHandler);
   factory.setConcurrency(3);
   return factory;
}
```

When I send and recive messages to this topic and print the received message in logs, I notice the following:

`2021-04-21 10:47:54.791 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  a.s.h.k.listener.MyEventListener - Received: mymessage (partition: 0)`

`2021-04-21 10:47:55.383 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-1-C-1] INFO  a.s.h.k.listener.MyEventListener - Received: mymessage (partition: 1)`

`2021-04-21 10:47:55.994 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  a.s.h.k.listener.MyEventListener  - Received: mymessage  (partition: 0)`

`2021-04-21 10:47:56.560 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-1-C-1] INFO  a.s.h.k.listener.MyEventListener - Received: mymessage  (partition: 1)`

`2021-04-21 10:47:57.197 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  a.s.h.k.listener.MyEventListener  - Received: mymessage  (partition: 0)`

As per docs and logs, setConcurrency creates two ListenerContainers and assign partition to them, in my case as the topic had only 2 partitions KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1 got partition 0 and KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-1-C-1 got partition 1 and that is to be seen in the logs as well.

Now what I did after this was inject KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry, asked registery for all listenercontainers and print partitions assigned to them like :

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.mytopic}", clientIdPrefix = "${kafka.mytopic.clientIdPrefix}", errorHandler = "messageErrorHandler")
public void processMessage(@Valid MyMessage message, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition) {
log.info("Received: " + message + " (partition: " + partition + ")");
log.info("Nr of containers {} ", registry.getAllListenerContainers().size());
registry.getAllListenerContainers().forEach(container -> {
        ((ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer)container).getContainers().forEach(c -> log.info("partition {}", ((ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer)c).getAssignedPartitions()));
    }); }
```

`2021-04-21 15:34:54.099 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-1-C-1] INFO  a.s.h.k.listener.MyEventListener - Nr of containers 1`
`org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0 [topic0-0, topic0-1]`

I was surprise to find that there was only one listener container and it has both partitions assigned to it. So now I am confused, what exactly happens when I do setConcurrency(3) ??

Answer (score 0):

When asking questions like this, it's besst to show your code and configuration; logs alone are rarely enough.

```
2021-04-21 10:47:54.791 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  a.s.h.k.listener.MyEventListener - Received: mymessage (partition: 0)

2021-04-21 10:47:55.383 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-1-C-1] INFO  a.s.h.k.listener.MyEventListener - Received: mymessage (partition: 1)
```

As you can see from the thread names in the log, the containers are assigned one partition each. The third container will be idle because you need at least 3 partitions for concurrency = 3.

Your final comment makes no sense; and the log you show doesn't match your `System.err.println` code.

**EDIT**

Per comments below, this works fine for me:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So67193049Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So67193049Application.class, args);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so67193049", topics = "so67193049", concurrency = "2")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so67193049").partitions(2).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry) {
        return args -> {
            Thread.sleep(5_000);
            registry.getAllListenerContainers().forEach(c ->
                    ((ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<?, ?>) c).getContainers()
                            .forEach(kc -> System.out.println(kc.getAssignedPartitions())));
        };
    }

}
```

```
2021-04-21 11:37:47.952[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18658[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[o67193049-1-C-1][0;39m [36mo.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m so67193049: partitions assigned: [so67193049-1]
[2m2021-04-21 11:37:47.953[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m18658[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[o67193049-0-C-1][0;39m [36mo.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m so67193049: partitions assigned: [so67193049-0]
[so67193049-0]
[so67193049-1]
```

Perhaps you have a separate `KMLC` `@Bean` declared? If so, use `getListenerContainers()` instead of `getAllListenerContainers()` (which returns all containers - beans as well as registrations for kafka listener methods.

**EDIT2**

It makes no difference where the registry is called from:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So67193049Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So67193049Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry;

    @KafkaListener(id = "so67193049", topics = "so67193049", concurrency = "2")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
        displayAssignments(this.registry, "listener:");
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so67193049").partitions(2).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry,
                KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {

        return args -> {
            template.send("so67193049", "foo");
            Thread.sleep(5_000);
            displayAssignments(registry, "runner:");
        };
    }

    private void displayAssignments(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry, String where) {
        registry.getAllListenerContainers().forEach(c ->
                ((ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<?, ?>) c).getContainers()
                        .forEach(kc -> System.out.println(where + kc.getAssignedPartitions())));
    }

}
```

```
foo
listener:[so67193049-0]
listener:[so67193049-1]
runner:[so67193049-0]
runner:[so67193049-1]
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Gary, I have edited configuration, strange enough KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry returns only one container on getAllListenerContainers().
I even print the size to be sure... could it be a bug ? I am using spring boot 2.4.5 which includes spring-kafka-2.6.7.jar.

Logs do show two containers but KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry prints just one. am I missing something here ?Could this be due to thread on which I invoke KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry  ?

Comment: Right; `@KafkaListener` creates a `ConcurrenMessageListenerContainer` which is the parent of `concurrency` `KafkaMessageListenerContainer`s. `getAssignedPartitions()` on the parent returns the aggregate. If you want to see the individual assignments, cast it to the concurrent container, and use `getContainers().forEach(c -> log.info(c.getAssignedPartitions()))`. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#message-listener-container

Comment: Casting doesn't work

`org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer cannot be cast to class org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer (org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer and org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer are in unnamed module of loader 'app')]. What else is interesting to log`

Irrespective: my assumption and docs were correct, logs prove the presence of 2 containers. Thanks again Gary, I got stumped because of KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry working.....improvement maybe ?

Comment: That makes no sense; only concurrent containers are ever registered for `@KafkaListener`s; even if the concurrency is 1,

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong ? Edited the code for listener

Comment: It's not clear what you mean; the registry will return the same data, regardless of which thread calls it.

Comment: If I inject KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry inside a pojo class (MyListener) which is decorated with Service annotation and then inside KafkaListener annotated method do the above I get Nr of containers 1 , and exception on casting if I try your recommendation. However If I do the same in say Configuration annotated pojo then I see the 3 containers with partitions. 

What happens if you move your code to listen() and do the print when you recieve a message i.e. inside the listen() ?

Comment: It makes no difference; I can't see how it's possible to get what you are seeing; if you can put together a minimal, complete, example and post it someplace like GitHub, I can take a look. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example